# Add items to view dynamically or hide and then show

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app that has a ListView of items. All of these items have an image representing the item. This image is shown in the ListView. However, some of the items have more images behind them that the user can show.

Our designer (:X) wishes that the images are shown directly inside the ListView. Each list item that has "more" images shows a "more" button. If the user clicks this button the list item should grow and display these images.

I'm seeing two options to implement this:

- add the "more" images dynamically to the items views. However I don't know if the standard ListView can handle it when some list items change. Is this a problem?
- add all "more" images when I create the item view (in `getView` inside my list adapter) and hide them by default and when the user clicks more simply show them.

Which of the two options is "better" in terms of performance and ease of implementation? IF these two options are stupid (because changing item views on demand) I could maybe argue to simply open another activity that show all the images but I need a good reason for this.

Comment: how about trying Expandable listview does it can be a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

ExpandableListView is your friend :)

Comment: Add had a look into it but an ExpandableListView seems no capable of supporting more then one item type (which is something I absolutely need)

Comment: If you want click on an item to expand it, the only option is use an ExpandableListView.